# Header("location: $random_link") Redirection issue PHP

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

Hey there I stuck into a problem with `header()` in php I create a database where i stored `10-15` random urls.
On every page reload the code below runs.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASSWORD","DB");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$link = null;
$link = $row['link'];
header("location: ".$link."");
```

but it is redirecting me to a single url every time.
it has to redirect me on a random url because it is working on localhost but when I upload this on server it is not working. It is redirecting me on a single url every time I contact to support of the server they cleared and disabled the server cache but I am still facing the issue.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Why `$link = null` and then an immediate re-declaration? Why use concatenation or a variable at all when you can do `"Location: {$row['link'}"` directly?

Comment: Did you try to echo `$link` var instead of redirect

Comment: This should do it, but you'll need to do some more debugging to find out what's wrong. Tip: If you only care about the `link` field, `SELECT link FROM ...` is far more efficient.

Comment: Thank you all for response i am getting your points and try hope i will successed

Comment: Sorry guys but not working

Comment: Please chat to your support because its server cache ask them to disable your server cache hope help this